# How to delete all data from a table in django inside a scrapy spider

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I have this scrapy spider that populates a table, 10 to 20 records maximum get scraped and inserted into the table. So I figured instead of seeing if a record exists and update it, it would be faster just to get rid of them and scrape new ones to take their place, what would you think is the better option seeing as how I practically have no data in my table? Also what is the django orm command to delete with the help of a where clause, e.g delete all records that have "cat" as name? Thank you very much

Comment: This sounds like pre-mature optimization.  If you really care, profile it and see, but it probably doesn't matter.  and I think [filter()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#filter) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks @ernie, I'd like to know what is "premature optimization" about cleansing the table to fetch new data? Thanks!

Comment: I'm saying comparing whether it's quicker to dump the table and rewrite it or whether to find and update particular records (especially for such a small table) is something that's not worth optimizing.  If you've got something that works, keep using it.  No reason to try and redo unless you're seeing that it's an actual bottleneck.  You'll spend more time rewriting the code than getting any performance difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Also what is the django orm command to delete with the help of a where clause, e.g delete all records that have "cat" as name?

This is very straightforward:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(name__contains="cat").delete()
```

I think that @ernie's comment about avoiding premature optimization is spot-on. But if you really care, you can delete all records with `MyModel.objects.all().delete()`.